# Mapping of two text documents with python

Tags: python, dataframe, deep-learning, nlp, text-mining

I have annotated some textual data and now I am trying to map it with the original text file to get more information out.
I have all information of the annotations in a JSON file, from which I successfully parsed all the relevant information. I stored the information as seen below.

1. Column = entity class
2. Column = starting point of the text
3. Column = length of the text (in char)
4. Column = value of entity label
5. Column = actual text that was annotated

My goal now is to include non-annotated text, as well. Not every single sentence or character of a text document has been annotated, but I want to include them to feed all the information into a DL-Algorithm. So every sentence that has not been annotated should be included and showing "None" as of entity class and entity label.

Appreciate any hint or help on that!

Thanks!

Comment: You should include 0.txt and 0.ann.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on how and where? @PramoteKuacharoen

Comment: Include them in your post, so they can be tested. It is difficult to test the code without input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information in your annotation file is not quite accurate. Since you stripped out white spaces, the length of the text should be adjusted properly.

```
def map_with_text(data_file, ann_file, out_file):

    annots = []
    # Read annotation information
    with open(ann_file, 'r') as file_in:
        for line in file_in:
            components = line.split('t')
            components = line.split("\t")
            label = components[0]
            begin = int(components[1])
            length = int(components[2])
            f_4 = int(components[3])
            f_5 = int(components[4])
            text = components[5].strip()
            annots.append((label, begin, length, f_4, f_5, text))

    annots = sorted(annots, key=lambda c: c[1])

    # Read text data
    with open(data_file, 'r') as original:
        original_text = original.read()

    length_original = len(original_text)

    # Get positions of text already annotated. Since it was 
    # stripped, we cannot use the length. You can modify it if
    # you think your information is accurate.
    # pos_tup = [(begin, begin+length)
    #           for _, begin, length, _, _, text in annots]

    pos_tup = [(begin, begin+len(text))
               for _, begin, length, _, _, text in annots]

    # Get position marker
    pos_marker = [0] + [e for l in pos_tup for e in l] + [length_original]
    
    # Ranges of positions of text which have not been annotated
    not_ann_pos = [(x, y)
                   for x, y in zip(pos_marker[::2], pos_marker[1::2])]

    # Texts which have not been annotated
    not_ann_txt = [original_text[start:stop]
                   for start, stop in not_ann_pos]

    # Include it in the list
    all_components = [(None, start, len(txt.strip()), None, None, txt.strip())
                      for start, txt in zip(pos_marker[::2], not_ann_txt) if len(txt.strip()) != 0]

    # Add annotated information
    all_components += annots

    # Sort by the start index
    all_components = sorted(all_components, key=lambda c: c[1])

    # Write ot the output file
    with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
        for a in all_components:
            f.write(str(a[0]) + "\t" + str(a[1]) + "\t" + str(a[2]) +
                    "\t" + str(a[3]) + "\t" + str(a[4]) + "\t" + str(a[5]) + "\n")


map_with_text('0.txt', '0.ann', 'out0.tsv')

# You can loop calling the function
#
#
```

Comment: It is tab delimited. You have to read with delimiter='\t'. df = pd.read_csv('out0.tsv', delimiter='\t')